# How to get the event when I enable my position?

Tags: windows-8

when I use the location feature in my App, I get a question at the first start if I want to allow the app to get my location.

Then later I can set this option over the charm bear without implementing it on my own.

Now the question:

How can I catch the event if a User change this option in the charm bar to true or false?

I added a picture, but its the german version of windows 8.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `GeoLocator` `StatusChanged` event to catch location service changes.

This is a C# example. You didn't tag the programming language but you can get the idea with this and use with your language of choice.

```
Geolocator location;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    location = new Geolocator();
    location.StatusChanged += location_StatusChanged;
}

async void location_StatusChanged(Geolocator sender, StatusChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var new_status = args.Status;
}
```

There are several status that you can get:

- notInitialized
- disabled
- notAvailable
- noData
- initializing
- ready

If you get a **disabled** status it means the user disabled location service permission. If you get one of the other it means the user has location service permission enabled.

**From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465148.aspx)**:

> If the user reenables location access after disabling it, there is no
>   notification to the app. The status property does not change and there
>   is no statusChanged event. Your app should create a new Geolocator
>   object and call getGeopositionAsync to try to get updated location
>   data, or subscribe again to positionChanged events. If the status then
>   indicates that location has been reenabled, clear any UI by which your
>   app previously notified the user that location services were disabled,
>   and respond appropriately to the new status.

Comment: the problem is, when I disable it and the enable it again I do not get the location_StatusChanged event

Comment: that is the way it works. it is not a problem of your app. You can use `PositionChanged` event and `GetGeopositionAsync` method to workaround this but you won't be 100% sure of it and you will get some delay depending on the report interval you have defined.